# package manager error on startup

Tags: apt, 20.04

I turned on my system today and a little red circle with a black minus sign in it . It read 'An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click from the right click window or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.  I ran the Sudo apt-get command and nothing happened.I am new to Linux and horrible with the terminal so please show me an easy way to rectify this problem.

Comment: Try running Synaptic Package Manager if you have it installed.

Comment: i dont have it but where can i install it? It is not in ubuntu software

Comment: `sudo apt install synaptic`